# The name "Count" does not exist in the current Context - How to fix

Tags: c#, winforms

So, we are making a score calculator in my class. The purpose is to add the scores you enter (i.e., 40+75+87...etc.) as well as count the number of scores you've added in and then provide you with an average. I keep receiving an error that the name 'Count' does not exist and it's also not actually add my scores together it simply puts the same number in (if I type 4 than 5 it doesn't display 9, it displays the number 5". Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int Count = 0;
        decimal Total = 0m;

    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Score = Convert.ToDecimal(txtScore.Text);
        decimal Total = Convert.ToDecimal (Score++);

        txtCount.Text = Count + 1;


        txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
        txtCount.Text = txtCount.ToString();
        txtAverage.Text = txtAverage.ToString();




    }
```

The expected output should be if I enter a score of '4', the count should display '1'. Once another score is written, it should display '2' as well as the sum of the two scores (i.e., enter '4' then '5' the score total should display '9')

Comment: put `int Count = 0;` and `decimal Total = 0m;` outside of constructor `public Form1() { ... }`

Comment: This code makes no sense: `txtCount.Text = txtCount.ToString();`. Should it be `txtCount.Text = Count.ToString();`?

Comment: And why are you converting a `decimal` to a `decimal` here: `decimal Total = Convert.ToDecimal (Score++);`? Should it be `decimal Total = Convert.ToDecimal (txtTotal.Text);`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the scope of your `Count` variable. Your current code is creating a local variable `Count` and `Total` inside `Form1()` constructor. Moving it out but still inside the same class `Form1` changes its scope and makes it accessible within the entire class.

```
int Count = 0;
decimal Total = 0m;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Your requirement looks simple enough. I bet this is what you want to achieve. Make sure you follow the code stated above first.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal Score = Convert.ToDecimal(txtScore.Text);

    Total += Score;
    Count++;

    decimal Average = Total/Count;

    txtCount.Text = Count.ToString();
    txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
    txtAverage.Text = Average.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You might be wondering why I also moved the `Total` variable outside the `Form1()` constructor. Since OP is not familiar with variable scopes then I'm assuming that he doesn't plan to use it as a local variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this one! I really appreciate you taking time to explain it as well!

Comment: FINALLY! Thank you so much for your help!!!!